# Append list of strings to XML file in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need a little bit of help for simplify a work and don't do it manually, if possible.

I have a list of strings:

```
<title>TITLE 1</title>
<title>TITLE 2</title>
<title>TITLE 3</title>
<title>TITLE 4</title>
<title>TITLE 5</title>
ETC...
```

There are over 1200 strings, just to let you know.
I also have an XML file with the same numbers of elements, each one in this format:

```
<game id="N">
    <url>URL</url>
    <img>IMG_URL</img>
    <date>DATE</date>
    <genre>GENRE</genre>
    <publisher>PUBLISHER</publisher>
    <developer>DEVELOPER</developer>
    <platforms>PLATFORMS</platforms>
    <vote>VOTE</vote>
    <review>REVIEW_URL</review>
    <info><![CDATA[INFORMATIONS]]></info>
</game>
```

What I need to do is appending for each of the `<title>` strings between each `</img>` and before `<date>`. It's possible to do it with VB.NET (I can't code in C#/C++) and, if yes, could someone please help me writing the code? Or maybe there is a simpler way with a regex, etc... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XElement and LINQ.

```
    Dim URI As String = "your path here"
    Dim fileXE As XElement
    'fileXE = XElement.Load(URI) ' - load XML,  uncomment in production

    'for testing = remove in production
    Dim titls As New List(Of String)
    titls.AddRange({"<title>TITLE 1</title>",
                    "<title>TITLE 2</title>",
                    "<title>TITLE 3</title>",
                    "<title>TITLE 4</title>",
                    "<title>TITLE 5</title>"})

    'for testing = remove in production
    fileXE = <games>
                 <game id="A">
                     <url>URL</url>
                     <img>IMG_URL</img>
                     <date>DATE</date>
                     <genre>GENRE</genre>
                     <publisher>PUBLISHER</publisher>
                     <developer>DEVELOPER</developer>
                     <platforms>PLATFORMS</platforms>
                     <vote>VOTE</vote>
                     <review>REVIEW_URL</review>
                     <info><![CDATA[INFORMATIONS]]></info>
                 </game>
                 <game id="B">
                     <url>URL</url>
                     <img>IMG_URL</img>
                     <date>DATE</date>
                     <genre>GENRE</genre>
                     <publisher>PUBLISHER</publisher>
                     <developer>DEVELOPER</developer>
                     <platforms>PLATFORMS</platforms>
                     <vote>VOTE</vote>
                     <review>REVIEW_URL</review>
                     <info><![CDATA[INFORMATIONS]]></info>
                 </game>
                 <game id="C">
                     <url>URL</url>
                     <img>IMG_URL</img>
                     <date>DATE</date>
                     <genre>GENRE</genre>
                     <publisher>PUBLISHER</publisher>
                     <developer>DEVELOPER</developer>
                     <platforms>PLATFORMS</platforms>
                     <vote>VOTE</vote>
                     <review>REVIEW_URL</review>
                     <info><![CDATA[INFORMATIONS]]></info>
                 </game>
             </games>
    'end for testing

    'get all img nodes
    Dim imgs As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = fileXE...<img>

    For Each el As XElement In imgs 'add one string per img
        Dim xe As XElement
        Try
            xe = XElement.Parse(titls(0)) 'get a title
            titls.RemoveAt(0) 'remove it
            el.AddAfterSelf(xe) 'add it
        Catch ex As Exception
            Stop
        End Try
    Next
    fileXE.Save(URI) 'save file
    Stop
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I've tried the code, but unfortunately it always Stop with Exception, but I can't figure it our what's wrong...

Comment: Sorry for the follow-up. I think the problem is `fileXE...<img>` because if I change it to something else for testing the code it goes forward. The crash is not relative to an Exception but it crash directly with error "No symbol loaded" in Visual Studio.

Comment: @ThePlayer96 - can you post your code please?

Comment: I've literally just copied and pasted it, so it's the same written by you

Comment: I've managed to make it works but if I change the titles list with mine (1290 elements with special characters sometimes) it stops working again. With some testing I could say that my list is the problem, since if I use just the first it works without problems.

Comment: @ThePlayer96 - I'd have to see the list elements causing a problem.

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was the "&" character in some titles. All okay now!

Comment: @ThePlayer96 - there are five characters that have to be escaped.
https://www.w3resource.com/xml/reserved-markup-characters.php